# library webcam-capture by sarxos not working on raspberry

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

i have a problem with the webcam-capture library for java on raspberry. This is my code:

```
    System.out.println("start");
    List<Webcam> list = Webcam.getWebcams();

    System.out.println("checking " + list.size() + " Webcams");
    for(Webcam webcam : list) {
        //do sth
    }
```

On windows i have the following output:

```
start
[main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture    
driver will be used
checking 0 Webcams
```

On my raspberry i only get

```
start
[main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture    
driver will be used
```

i tried to figure out the problematic code in the library and i found out that it exits at:

```
executor.awaitTermination(timeout, tunit);
```

in WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams()

the parameters are 9223372036854775807 and
MILLISECONDS

why doesn't it work ("the project is portable (WinXP, Win7, Win8, Linux, Mac, Raspberry Pi) and does not require any additional software to be installed on the PC.").

is there maybe any other library that is that easy?

Comment: Have you tried asking a question on the github project page, where they might have some specific knowledge of this issue?

Comment: i looked on their homepage, in this forum, at linkedin for an email but i didn't find one... good to know that i can contact at github :D i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to record the solution I provided in the [ticket](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/375) created in Webcam Capture API project on Github in case anyone has the same issue and tries stackoverflow first.

The problem lies in the default driver which does not always run well on Raspberry Pi (only one [BridJ](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ) version supports Raspberry Pi but it hasn't been released to Maven Central). To workaround this issue one can replace default driver which depends on BridJ by a different one, e.g. [webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-drivers/driver-v4l4j) which is most stable on Raspberry Pi, or by adding BridJ 0.6.3-SNAPSHOT to classpath instead of 0.6.2.

In case of webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j the JARs you have to include in your classpath are:

For Webcam Capture 0.3.10:

- [v4l4j-0.9.1-r507.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/sarxos/v4l4j/0.9.1-r507/v4l4j-0.9.1-r507.jar)
- [webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j-0.3.10-20140923.154112-11.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/sarxos/webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j/0.3.10-SNAPSHOT/webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j-0.3.10-20140923.154112-11.jar)

Or Webcam Capture 0.3.11:

- [v4l4j-0.9.1-r507.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/sarxos/v4l4j/0.9.1-r507/v4l4j-0.9.1-r507.jar)
- [webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j-0.3.11-20150713.101304-10.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/sarxos/webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j/0.3.11-SNAPSHOT/webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j-0.3.11-20150713.101304-10.jar)

After these are added, BridJ JAR can be removed from classpath as not required any more.

The code:

```
static {
  Webcam.setDriver(new V4l4jDriver()); // this is important
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("V4L4J Webcam Capture Driver Demo");
  frame.add(new WebcamPanel(Webcam.getDefault()));
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

For more details I'm redirecting everyone interested to the [ticket](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/375) where issue has been resolved.